# MAX_HEAPIFY implementation

Tags: javascript, recursion, heap

I wrote JavaScript code to build a max heapify which maintains the max-heap property, but I have many questions regarding the implementation:

> array I test on: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16]

When I test on the array when it is sorted I got:

> [ 16, 14, 9, 10, 7, 8, 3, 1, 4, 2 ]

While unsorted I got:

> [ 16, 14, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1 ]

Why or why not is the max-heapify affected by the array being sorted?

I find that when the array is sorted the solution is:

> [ 16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1 ]

Why did I get a different solution when the array is sorted, even if I find my implementation is right according to the pseudocode in CLRS?

Could you specify another procedure that doesn't use recursion while achieving the same functionality?

```
function BuildMaxHeap(array){
 for(var i = Math.floor(array.length / 2); i >= 0; i--){
    MAX_HEAPIFY(array, i);
 }
 return array;
}

function MAX_HEAPIFY(array, i) {
 var left = 2 * i + 1;
 var right = 2 * i + 2;
 var largest = i;
 if(left <= array.length && array[left] > array[largest]){
    largest = left;
  }
 if(right <= array.length && array[right] > array[largest]){
    largest = right;
 }
 if(largest != i){
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[largest];
    array[largest] = temp;
    MAX_HEAPIFY(array, largest);
 }
}
```

Comment: I was really asking about why the code is not performing as it is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, min/max heaps made from a set of numbers can have multiple configurations of their leaves depending on the order in which they are inserted.

You might think this 'global ordering' of leaves might arise from some emergent behavior of the underlying heap property, but a given array doesn't have a one-to-one correspondence with a particular configuration.

This occurs because of how a child is inserted and *bubbled-up* (swapped with parents), which will stop as soon as it is smaller than it's parent - of which there can be multiple valid candidates for a position in the heap.

This was confusing to me when I first implemented a heap as well.

Comment: getting peoples what i do

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question;

just to be sure,

```
function buildMaxHeap(array){
 return array.sort((a,b)=>b-a);
}
```

Will also return a valid array.

Since the goal is only to provide a tree where

- root has maximum value key
- key stored at a non-root is at most the value of its parent
- any path from root to leaf is in non-increasing order
- left and right sub-trees are unrelated

( http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/cscB63h/w07/lectures/tut02.txt )

The algorithm swaps parents and children until those 4 conditions are met, so yes, if you start with a different array, then also the output can be different.

From a CodeReview perspective:

- `MAX_HEAPIFY` -> JavaScript follows lowerCamelCase, so maxHeapify
- Your indentation is off, try using something like http://jsbeautifier.org/
- why call one function `MAX_HEAPIFY` and the other `BuildMaxHeap`, those names resemble each other and do not tell the reader what they do.

Other than that, there is not much to say.